# Remove files using a unix-like pattern

Tags: java, file-io

I would like to implement something equivalent to the unix command 'rm foo*' using Java. Obviously, I want it to be multi platform. I know that this can be done using the FilenameFilter class and File.delete() method, but I was wondering if I can perform this simple operation in a less verbose way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in commons-io for [org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html).

```
for (File file : new File(".").listFiles(new WildcardFilter("foo*"))) {
  file.delete();
}
```